# Stay compatible with (changed) doclet API on jdk7 and jdk8

Tags: java, maven, deprecated

I'm developing a maven plugin that uses the Doclet API (`ConfigurationImpl.getInstance()` and `HtmlDocletWriter.commentTagsToString()` for example). This API is contained in tools.jar that comes with the JDK.

On jdk8, these methods don't exist anymore so the plugin breaks.

I'm now looking for a way to make my plugin work with both jdk7 and 8.

I'm thinking about using an interface that offers a stable API and providing different implementations for each JDK. However, I'm not sure how I can switch/load the correct implementation. Mind that everything needs to be packaged in the same jar (the maven plugin).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a factory that will give you an instance of your interface. Within the factory you check the `java.version` system property. If it is `>= 8` then you will instantiate the interface implementation for JDK 8, otherwise the one for JDK 7. Those implementation classes must only be loaded in that factory. So you won't get a problem with missing APIs, because the class won't be loaded that depends on that API.

Comment: That's indeed what I was thinking. The only problem is that I can't do this in one jar module since it'll need both jdk7 and jdk8 to compile (which isn't possible). I guess there's no escaping putting both implementations in separate modules.

Comment: @bertvh you are right, you need to have different compilations runs for each of those implementations.